# Access device settings of Motorola MC67 using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce, motorola

I am new to C# and WM/CE OS as well. I need to access and update device settings of Motorola MC67 device using C#, but can't find anything related to it anywhere. Specifically, I want to update Settings>>Connections>>Existing Connections>>Select a profile and Update APN value.

Please suggest/help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup/change GPRS emtries using the MS DMProcessConfig API call and a wap provisioning xml for CM_GPRSEntries
Although the site states CE6 it is valid for WM6 too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee497113%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

Example xml at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee498033%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

You may also query the settings, for example using RAPIconfig.

Comment: I had problems implementing your solution, but I had it done using a similar method. But now I have a weird problem in it. See if you can make something from this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181592/windows-mobile-updating-gprs-settings-using-c-sharp)